# Не отображает картинку HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, изображения

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6c7279;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  background-color: #000;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Container
===================*/

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Header
===================*/

.header {
  padding: 38px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
}

.header__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #515369;
  padding: 38px;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
}

.nav__link {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  margin-left: 53px;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Intro
===================*/

.intro {
  height: 750px;
  background: #31344e url(img/intro-bg.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo:400i|Open+Sans:700|Raleway:400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Мой сайт</title>

</head>

<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__inner">
      <div class="header__logo">
        <img src="img/ActiveBoxlogo.png" alt="">
      </div>


      <nav class="nav">
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Works</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Our Team</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Testimonials</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Download</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="intro"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

**КАРТИНКА В ПАПКЕ ЕСТЬ!**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас путь прописан неверно. Поскольку файл css лежит не в корне, а в папке, то сначала надо из неё выйти в корень, а затем уже зайти в img:

```
url(../img/intro-bg.jpg)
```